# Advice for choosing a book in Complex Analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, book-recommendation

I am a 4th year mathematics undergraduate student. I took a "Complex Variables" (complex analysis made less rigorous) course in second year, though I feel at the time I wasn't able to properly appreciate the subject since I was in second year. Now, I am in 4th year and I have a background in real analysis, including two introductory course in the subject, a course in measure theory, a course in topology, and (currently) a course in functional analysis. I am looking for a complex analysis book that I will enjoy in my spare time.

What I am looking for:

1. Most importantly, **lots of exercises that have (at least some) selected solutions**
2. A book that explains well and emphasizes the theory

Something under $200 for a physical copy would be nice (though beggers can't be choosers).

Thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: For (1) you may try ["A Collection of Problems on Complex Analysis"](https://www.amazon.com/Collection-Problems-Complex-Analysis-Mathematics/dp/0486669130) by Volkovyskii et al.. I haven't read this book, but its TOC seems quite comprehensive.

Comment: "Visual Complex Analysis" by Tristan Needham.

Comment: Depends on what kind of book you like. Do you like for example Rudin's style of writing (to the point, clear and with a few examples sprinkled here and there)? If yes, then I'd strongly suggest Henri Cartan's text. Chapters 1,2,3 constitute a huge part of a first complex analysis course; the theory is explained very clearly. Or do you prefer a much more conversational and expository style? In that case, I'd suggest something like Stein and Shakarchi (I'm biased so I like Cartan's text better, but Stein has more problems).

Answer (score 3):

Serge Lang wrote a book called *Complex Analysis* (Springer GTM 103) that has an accompanying solutions manual by Rami Shakarchi somewhere. According to an [Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2QIAPBZOF054I/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0387985921) it has a topological flavor, which might be appreciated since you have prior experience with topology.

Note: I have not read the book.

Answer (score 2):

*Visual Complex Analysis* by Tristan Needham is often recommended. It is a first course on complex analysis.
Here is a [preview](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ogz5FjmiqlQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: The book of the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try the book "Introduction to Complex Analysis" here: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/notes/complex-analysis-course/.
I've read it, and I think it is good.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this page](https://www.math.unipd.it/%7Epietro/Analisi_complessa.html) and download "basic complex analysis" and "selected topics in complex analysis". They are **really good** notes.